# python: accessing class variable with or without reference

Tags: python

code:

```
class Example:

    pos_list=[]
    last_cell=0

    def setText(self):
        last_cell = 10
        pos_list.append(int(10))              #Line 1
        print pos_list , last_cell            #Line 2
```

Error: global name 'pos_list' is not defined.

if i access **pos_list** in Line 1 and Line 2 as

```
   self.pos_List or Example.pos_list
```

then 
      no error [ which is fine as i'm accessing it as a instance(self) or class(Example)    variable ]

but what about **last_cell** ?
i am  accessing it without either self or class reference. But in case of **pos_list** python interpreter was forcing me to use either those two references.

why am able to access last_cell without any reference ?

Comment: You're missing a parenthesis on line 1 :)

Comment: Please do the official Python tutorial - Python's object model is quite different from what you may have learned from more mainstream OOPLs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You aren't. You're just creating a local variable that happens to have the same name.

```
class Example:
    x = 1
    def f(self):
        x = 2
Example().f()
print(Example.x) #=> 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you declare last_cell as a local variable. When doing `pos_list.append()` you are trying to call a method on something that is undefined, which generates an error.